# Regular ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken exceptions - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf, bots

I have a Rails 4.2.6 app (also running Devise) in production with the [Exception Notification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) gem installed and working. I get waves in hundreds of `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` errors (sample below), usually 2-3 per minute for hours at a time. I am not too clued up on the security side of Rails but I guess this is a robot attempting a CSRF attack of some form.

It always comes from the same IP address (107.15.69.216) which looks like one from Raleigh, North Carolina, USA.

Is it a robot?

And, Is there something I need to do about this or is the error simply proving that Devise's CSRF attack protection is working as it should?

```
An ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken occurred in registrations#create:

  ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken



-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

  * URL        : https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
  * HTTP Method: POST
  * IP address : 107.15.69.216
  * Parameters : {"Q/Zcl9vJY8K1NPSRoHXnCQrZaPF8pu/uXVPyCfW8RnAQclIPvjOvpXqFLY TPUg9uBDmGWG5lMd8vzgSuGw79LAE d03xLFVtA/JUrX7cKmb3u Wrd7xS2LsMlSj2zAvtxmSPkGpoKR8e1p/XAQ exuiMte/fyXnLSrVjMfmzpNNxr7MSamyRHFVQan3LaxMJUq 02h4D1L4psFwbwl9k27W45G8FT9LaS2HG7g7y/rsxAon8ovLUgQNY2HcRMf7XlZxmxK20kDWfcLLn8DrpwY/bSW6mGsxAgD0CkapGj5LU7Smg5FvtR5qFn7q Ey9F0YdlMpE5/MqYWQNINgpzIxokxY1JyEdg5WphcGExuXjPDN3ChYUrkZG4h PAe7LuaGSQjyTOY/K4/O/iLODlBcM EqxCVZY8J04"=>nil, "controller"=>"registrations", "action"=>"create"}
  * Timestamp  : 2017-01-12 14:00:54 UTC
  * Server : sgp1-iml-01
  * Rails root : /home/app-name-deploy/apps/app-name/releases/20161212034105
  * Process: 11031

-------------------------------
Session:
-------------------------------

  * session id: [FILTERED]
  * data: {}

-------------------------------
Environment:
-------------------------------

  * CONTENT_LENGTH                                 : 420
  * CONTENT_TYPE                                   : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  * GATEWAY_INTERFACE                              : CGI/1.2
  * HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL                             : no-cache
  * HTTP_CONNECTION                                : close
  * HTTP_HOST                                      : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  * HTTP_USER_AGENT                                : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
  * HTTP_VERSION                                   : HTTP/1.0
  * HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR                           : 107.15.69.216
  * HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO                         : https
  * ORIGINAL_FULLPATH                              : /
  * ORIGINAL_SCRIPT_NAME                           :
  * PATH_INFO                                      : /
  * QUERY_STRING                                   :
  * REMOTE_ADDR                                    : 127.0.0.1
  * REQUEST_METHOD                                 : POST
  * REQUEST_PATH                                   : /
  * REQUEST_URI                                    : /
  * ROUTES_42047240_SCRIPT_NAME                    :
  * SCRIPT_NAME                                    :
  * SERVER_NAME                                    : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  * SERVER_PORT                                    : 443
  * SERVER_PROTOCOL                                : HTTP/1.1
  * SERVER_SOFTWARE                                : puma 3.6.0 Sleepy Sunday Serenity
  * action_controller.instance                     : #<RegistrationsController:0x00000006f6a0d0>
  * action_dispatch.backtrace_cleaner              : #<Rails::BacktraceCleaner:0x00000005458648>
  * action_dispatch.cookies                        : #<ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar:0x00000006f537b8>
  * action_dispatch.cookies_digest                 :
  * action_dispatch.cookies_serializer             : json
  * action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_salt          : encrypted cookie
  * action_dispatch.encrypted_signed_cookie_salt   : signed encrypted cookie
  * action_dispatch.http_auth_salt                 : http authentication
  * action_dispatch.key_generator                  : #<ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator:0x00000006945560>
  * action_dispatch.logger                         : #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x00000006d22570>
  * action_dispatch.parameter_filter               : [:password]
  * action_dispatch.redirect_filter                : []
  * action_dispatch.remote_ip                      : 107.15.69.216
  * action_dispatch.request.content_type           : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  * action_dispatch.request.formats                : [#<Mime::Type:0x000000053404e0 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html", @hash=672552242721212245>]
  * action_dispatch.request.parameters             : {"Q/Zcl9vJY8K1NPSRoHXnCQrZaPF8pu/uXVPyCfW8RnAQclIPvjOvpXqFLY TPUg9uBDmGWG5lMd8vzgSuGw79LAE d03xLFVtA/JUrX7cKmb3u Wrd7xS2LsMlSj2zAvtxmSPkGpoKR8e1p/XAQ exuiMte/fyXnLSrVjMfmzpNNxr7MSamyRHFVQan3LaxMJUq 02h4D1L4psFwbwl9k27W45G8FT9LaS2HG7g7y/rsxAon8ovLUgQNY2HcRMf7XlZxmxK20kDWfcLLn8DrpwY/bSW6mGsxAgD0CkapGj5LU7Smg5FvtR5qFn7q Ey9F0YdlMpE5/MqYWQNINgpzIxokxY1JyEdg5WphcGExuXjPDN3ChYUrkZG4h PAe7LuaGSQjyTOY/K4/O/iLODlBcM EqxCVZY8J04"=>nil, "controller"=>"registrations", "action"=>"create"}
  * action_dispatch.request.path_parameters        : {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"create"}
  * action_dispatch.request.query_parameters       : {}
  * action_dispatch.request.request_parameters     : {"Q/Zcl9vJY8K1NPSRoHXnCQrZaPF8pu/uXVPyCfW8RnAQclIPvjOvpXqFLY TPUg9uBDmGWG5lMd8vzgSuGw79LAE d03xLFVtA/JUrX7cKmb3u Wrd7xS2LsMlSj2zAvtxmSPkGpoKR8e1p/XAQ exuiMte/fyXnLSrVjMfmzpNNxr7MSamyRHFVQan3LaxMJUq 02h4D1L4psFwbwl9k27W45G8FT9LaS2HG7g7y/rsxAon8ovLUgQNY2HcRMf7XlZxmxK20kDWfcLLn8DrpwY/bSW6mGsxAgD0CkapGj5LU7Smg5FvtR5qFn7q Ey9F0YdlMpE5/MqYWQNINgpzIxokxY1JyEdg5WphcGExuXjPDN3ChYUrkZG4h PAe7LuaGSQjyTOY/K4/O/iLODlBcM EqxCVZY8J04"=>nil}
  * action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie: {}
  * action_dispatch.request_id                     : b8c1d2ef-0272-4e58-928d-8d02e8c5ad28
  * action_dispatch.routes                         : #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x00000005032e10>
  * action_dispatch.secret_key_base                : 72399ae7d71631b9bf5c19fe5e63e6e6c7163f37cdf8d1bb853cb77b53b6de0d20ce168a0e4a6fc87fadeb09b122a30d09ff9103f2f05a6bd5660c4c00f57392
  * action_dispatch.secret_token                   :
  * action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions       : false
  * action_dispatch.show_exceptions                : true
  * action_dispatch.signed_cookie_salt             : signed cookie
  * devise.mapping                                 : #<Devise::Mapping:0x00000006939c60>
  * puma.config                                    : #<Puma::Configuration:0x00000002f1e940>
  * puma.socket                                    : #<UNIXSocket:0x00000006f768a8>
  * rack.after_reply                               : []
  * rack.errors                                    : #<File:0x0000000230dac0>
  * rack.hijack                                    : #<Puma::Client:0x00000006f76880>
  * rack.hijack?                                   : true
  * rack.input                                     : #<StringIO:0x00000006f762b8>
  * rack.multiprocess                              : false
  * rack.multithread                               : true
  * rack.request.cookie_hash                       : {}
  * rack.request.form_hash                         : {"Q/Zcl9vJY8K1NPSRoHXnCQrZaPF8pu/uXVPyCfW8RnAQclIPvjOvpXqFLY TPUg9uBDmGWG5lMd8vzgSuGw79LAE d03xLFVtA/JUrX7cKmb3u Wrd7xS2LsMlSj2zAvtxmSPkGpoKR8e1p/XAQ exuiMte/fyXnLSrVjMfmzpNNxr7MSamyRHFVQan3LaxMJUq 02h4D1L4psFwbwl9k27W45G8FT9LaS2HG7g7y/rsxAon8ovLUgQNY2HcRMf7XlZxmxK20kDWfcLLn8DrpwY/bSW6mGsxAgD0CkapGj5LU7Smg5FvtR5qFn7q Ey9F0YdlMpE5/MqYWQNINgpzIxokxY1JyEdg5WphcGExuXjPDN3ChYUrkZG4h PAe7LuaGSQjyTOY/K4/O/iLODlBcM EqxCVZY8J04"=>nil}
  * rack.request.form_input                        : #<StringIO:0x00000006f762b8>
  * rack.request.form_vars                         : [FILTERED]
  * rack.request.query_hash                        : {}
  * rack.request.query_string                      :
  * rack.run_once                                  : false
  * rack.session                                   : #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x00000006f6bea8>
  * rack.session.options                           : #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session::Options:0x00000006f6be08>
  * rack.url_scheme                                : http
  * rack.version                                   : [1, 3]
  * warden                                         : Warden::Proxy:58416640 @config={:default_scope=>:user, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:rememberable, :database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>#<Devise::Delegator:0x00000007b40dc8>}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is a bot. It is trying to go through your devise's registration form. Just in case check if you have this code in your main layout: `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`. It can be accidently deleted after rewriting your layout.

This is the info about IP address from which you were under attack: http://pastebin.com/c1Zb5tcP

You can try to cut spammer using your resources with [rack-attack gem](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack)
There is a simple [configuration](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/wiki/Example-Configuration) to start with it, after installation.

There is also another solution, to create a rule in the INPUT chain in your IPtables, and block traffic from the IP address you provided, in case that you have access to your server:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 107.15.69.216 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have the `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` line in the layout. The rack-attack gem looks interesting. I'll check it out, thanks.